# Responsive Issue

Tags: css, html, size

I'm trying to make the text on my page change to however the page is sized. For example, the line will end at a different place depending on the resolution of the screen so that all the text can be fit in the div.

I'm sure there's a very simple way to do this but I can't figure it out at all.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: have you google it before posting?

Comment: As long as none of the texts parent elements have a defined width it should happen automatically...

Answer (score 2):

If you're thinking responsive, you have to learn to relinquish a certain amount of control over your design. Line lengths will change on different devices, but that's expected behaviour...

If you're really just starting out, you should read the [original article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) that started it all. [Ethan Marcotte's book](http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design) is also indispensable.

If you're looking to make headline text shrink/grow to fit the available space (and you're used to using jQuery) then check out [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

media queries:

```
@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  body { background: red; }
}
```